# Reference text content of current event with Google AMP "on" action

Tags: html, dom, amp-html, google-amp

I am trying to rewrite our stack to be AMP valid

I have the following pattern :

1. A search bar is available to type in a query.
2. When you type text (input-debounce), an **amp-list** is shown (unhidden) and a new state variable **searchQuery** is created with the content of **event.value** (the search bar input value)
3. A call is made to endpoint **A** by an **amp-state** component (with **searchQuery** as a parameter)
4. The results are displayed in the amp-list as links with some text content (let's call it **title**) and a blank href (**#**)

Now what I would like is that when you click a result from the list, the value of the search input be set the value of the clicked element. Like an autocomplete/selector of some sort.

What I tried is having an **on** attribute on each list item with

`tap:AMP.setState({searchQuery: event.value})`

### But when I click a result, the search bar value is always set to **null**.

I tried : `event.value` `event.target.value` `event.innerHTML` `event.innerContent` `event.text`
Also tried replacing the link (**a**) to a **span** a button and such, same result.

Is this actually possible with AMP ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to bind the `input` element's value to `searchQuery` for this to work. Here is a simplified sample (without an amp-list):

```
  <input type=text [value]=searchQuery on="input-debounced:AMP.setState({searchQuery: event.value})">

  <button on="tap:AMP.setState({searchQuery: 'test'})">
    Click
  </button>
  <div [text]=searchQuery></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I think I didn't explain what I was trying to achieve clearly enough. What I need to do is :

1. take INPUT value and store in SEARCHQUERY (done)
2. take SEARCHQUERY and fetch JSON with this SEARCHQUERY in the url (done)
3. list these results by name (done)
4. when the user clicks a result from the list, the SEARCHQUERY in set to the NAME of the clicked item

The problem being I cannot find a way to reference a simple div or p or a element with the event. For an input it is event.value for a selector it is event.option but what is it for a common block elem ?

Comment: That's what I tried to demonstrate with the button. The key is to set the AMP state when the user clicks on an item using `on="tap:AMP.setState({searchQuery: 'test'})"`. You need to generate the on tap action inside the amp-list.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to access the element value of the needed item directly, with a standard block type html element (like div, span, p, a...).
However what I did (and works) is to use a selector, even amp-selector and simply use the event.targetOption to get the value of the result being clicked...

Its not exactly what I wanted but it is functionally equivalent so it will do.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments I understand that you are using some html element other than an input, as a list item and therefore can't access corresponding value using event. Although this is not directly possible, this functionality can be mimicked by using AMP.setState. I assume your amp-list template looks something like follows :

```
<template type="amp-mustache">
    <span class="list-item">{{list-option}}</span>
</template>
```

You can try embedding the option value in the setState() for each list item using amp-mustache inside the template as follows :

```
<template type="amp-mustache">
  <span class="list-item" on="tap:AMP.setState({searchQuery : {{list-option}} })" >{{list-option}}</span>
</template>
```